# Searching Serial Ports with IOKit - Swift

Tags: macos, swift, serial-port, iokit

I'm trying to understand IOKit and how it allows me to access serial ports in a Swift program.

The class I'm manipulating at the moment is as follows:

```
import Foundation

import Cocoa

import IOKit.serial.IOSerialKeys



class Serial {

    init() {
    }

    @IBOutlet var serialListPullDown : NSPopUpButton!

    func refreshSerialList(defaultprompt: String) {


        // remove everything from the pull down list
        serialListPullDown?.removeAllItems()

        // ask for all the serial ports
        IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue), io_iterator_t)

    }
}
```

Based on what I've read I think I've setup IOServiceMatchingServices correctly but I'm getting several errors such as "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" and "'o_iterator_t.Type' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutualPointer'"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few different issues going on in there -- let's get your imports squared away first. It looks like you need these two:

```
import IOKit
import IOKit.serial
```

For the parameters, it'll be easier to see what we're working with if we define them as local variables, like so:

```
// this one's easy, just grabbing a constant from IOKit.serial
let masterPort: mach_port_t = kIOMasterPortDefault
// here we get back an Unmanaged<CFMutableDictionary> and need to convert it to
// a CFDictionary using takeRetainedValue()
let classesToMatch: CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue).takeRetainedValue()
// the iterator that will contain the results of IOServiceGetMatchingServices
var matchingServices: io_iterator_t = 0
```

And lastly, you call the method:

```
// note that the last parameter is an UnsafeMutablePointer<io_iterator_t>
// so we need to prefix matchingServices with an ampersand (&)
let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, classesToMatch, &matchingServices)
if kernResult == KERN_SUCCESS {
    // success
} else {
    // error
}
```

This feels pretty near the edge of what Swift can handle right now -- definitely read these two pages well before going further:

- [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) (**Pointers** section)
- [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) (**Unmanaged Objects** section)

Lastly, make sure you can get into the converted Swift declarations for the `IOKit` framework. There are a lot of useful comments and you'll be able to see which parameters and return values are unmanaged or pointers (since I don't think this framework's official documentation has been updated yet).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this up, that truly provided a wealth of information! I've implemented all of the segments suggested which resulted in no syntax errors (Which always gets me excited) and I've been attempting to run it. The program builds and runs however I receive the error: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)". I've read that this can result from the misuse of pointers, could that be likely? The error flags the closing parentheses of my refreshSerialList() function which is unlikely to be the issue itself. Could the pointers be causing this issue perhaps?